# Convert Hex to Decimal (Lat / Lon)?

Tags: java, hex, decimal, latitude-longitude

I got a latitude and longitude values in hexadecimal:

```
0AF6CF83
D89B2933
```

Converting them to decimal I got...

```
 183947139
-660920013
```

The problem is, how to get those decimals in the following format using Java?

```
 18.3947139
-66.0920013
```

This is how I actually converting Hex to Decimal:

```
public static int hex2Decimal(String s) {
    long longValue = Long.parseLong(s, 16);
    int intValue = (int)longValue;
    return intValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first parse the hex value to an `int`, then <strike>multiply that by `1e-7` *(faster to multiply by `1e-7` that divide by `1e7`)*</strike> divide that by `1e7`.
   <sup>Thanks to @RolandIllig for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007972/convert-hex-to-decimal-lat-lon/39008116#comment65368087_39008116) the precision issue.</sup>

However, [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) will not allow parsing an 8 digit hex value to a negative integer value, i.e. when the high bit is on.

In Java 8, you'd do this:

```
public static double hex2Decimal(String s) {
    return Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 16) / 1e7;
}
```

If your code needs to run on Java versions before 8, do this:

```
public static double hex2Decimal(String s) {
    return (int)Long.parseLong(s, 16) / 1e7;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(hex2Decimal("0AF6CF83"));
System.out.println(hex2Decimal("D89B2933"));
```

*Output*

```
18.3947139
-66.0920013
```

Comment: Don't multiply with 1.0e-7, divide by 1.0e7 instead. It is more precise.

Comment: @RolandIllig An `int` value has less than 10 digits of precision, so the result of this calculation is only accurate to 9-10 digits. `double` has 15-17 digits of precision, so any impreciseness of `1e-7` is meaningless.

Comment: Accepted, but dividing has the benefit that you can just use Double.toString and get the expected result, instead of having to use a format like `%.7f`.

Answer (score 0):

The first number looks very easy: just divide the `int` result by 10.0e6, which is 10 millions.

Comment: A signed int can't hold 8 hex digits.

Comment: Conceptually it can, but `parseInt` throws an exception if it overflows.

Comment: By the way, the actual result of `hex2Decimal("D89B2933")` is `-660920013`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I didn't know that Java was this strict.

Comment: Looking at the actual and the expected number makes it obvious, since the digits are the same.